# What kind of encryption should I follow for the best? .NET & SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, encryption, tripledes

I am planning an application where I store critical data like passwords and credit card details on sql server. I plan to use TRIPLEDES. What I need to know is that, is that enough? or do you think I should go for something like a digital certificate or "something else"? I am totally alien to security aspects related to encryption. Can someone let me know what should I really be doing?

Comment: You shouldn't *encrypt* passwords, you should store them *salted and hashed*.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using microsoft identity, this provides a simple mechanism for creating a secure environment which salted and hashed passwords out of the box. http://www.asp.net/identity